# SSRS Report - Dynamic Connection String and Parameters

Tags: reporting-services

I am building a SSRS report portal to run various reports. One of the requirement is to pass the database connection string (server name, database, username and password) dynamically to the report.

Please let me know how to achieve this. I am new to SSRS report.

Thanks
Sri

Answer (score 8):

You should make sure that your datasource is embedded in the report.

And you can set your Connection string dynamically using an expression.

[image: DataSource Setup]

There is some more information on dynamically setting connection strings [Here](http://sqlserverrider.wordpress.com/2011/11/04/dynamic-data-source-for-ssrs-reports/)

Answer (score 5):

You can use parametr and experssion for connection string of datasource

```
="Data Source=Server;User ID=sa;Password=sa;Initial Catalog="+Parameters!Database.Value
```