# Conditional excel file selection as SSRS data source

Tags: sql-server, excel, reporting-services, conditional-statements, ssrs-2012

I build SSRS reports in Visual Studio 2013 and I have to use excel file as data source. Each month new .xlsx file is uploaded into the folder of the following structure: `\\[yyyy-yy]\[yyyy.mm]\{somefilename}[ mmm yy].xlsx`.

Is it possible to specify SSRS data source conditionally, so it will pick up the latest file available?

P.S. I know that the best solution would be a stored procedure on SQL side to pump all data to server, but unfortunately this is not the case.

Comment: You can set the connection string dynamically with an expression. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/19830931/2033717

Comment: not sure how you're currently defining the datasource, but connection strings can be expressions, so you can try using an expression to build the connection string based on current date